# How do I request a php page for every url using htacess?

Tags: apache

Suppose i have the following url

```
http://host/testscripts/php_Env
```

When I request this page, the htaccess should append .php to it

so that new url becomes 
         enter code here
            `enter code here`http://host/testscripts/php_Env.php

I have the following htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^php_[a-zA-Z_]+$  $1.php   [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the parentheses.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^php_([a-zA-Z_]+)$  $1.php   [NC,L]
```